# OkHttp Interceptor add post params is returning 400 response

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, interceptor

This is my encrypt function. 
I have to change the endpoint and add parameters at Post/Put request. Get is working.
When I remove  `.post(formBody.build())` function. It's response is 200, 
but if I add `post(formBody)`. It will return 400.
Any solution?

```
private fun encryptMethod(chain: Interceptor.Chain, method: String): Response {

    var params: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

    if (chain.request().body() is FormBody){
        params = getHttpUrlParams(chain.request().body() as FormBody)
    }

    val url: HttpUrl = chain.request().url()
    val urlBuilder = url.newBuilder()

    //將舊的path改成params
    var pathParams = ""
    for (position in 0 until url.pathSegments().size) {
        if (position < url.pathSize()) pathParams += "/"
        pathParams += url.pathSegments()[position]
    }

    //更新path
    for (position in 0 until url.pathSegments().size) {
        urlBuilder.removePathSegment(0)
    }
    urlBuilder.addPathSegment("api")

    params["path"] = pathParams
    params["method"] = method
    params["timestamp"] = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000).toString()

    Log.i("ddd","params $params ")

    val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
    //將encryptParams加入post
    for ((key, value) in NetworkEncrypt.encryptParams(params)) {
        formBody.add(key, value)
    }

    val builder = chain
        .request()
        .newBuilder()
        .post(formBody.build())
        .url(urlBuilder.build())

    Log.i("ddd",builder.build().toString())

    val request = builder.build()

    return chain.proceed(request)
}

 private fun getHttpUrlParams(formBody: FormBody?): HashMap<String, String> {
    val paramMap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    if (formBody != null) {
        for (i in 0 until formBody.size()) {
            paramMap[formBody.name(i)] = formBody.value(i)
        }
    }
    return paramMap
}
```

Comment: @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/anything")
suspend fun getTest(
    @Field("path") path: String
): Response<String>

If Interceptor path data != services path data
will get 400

so I dont know how to change feild

Comment: This code example requires work from a potential answerer to run, consider making a complete example e.g. a single file with a main method that shows the broken behaviour. http://sscce.org/

You could start with this file and edit it https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/guide/PostExample.java

Comment: Please check.
I mark fixme.

https://github.com/PascalTang/OkhttpApplication